# TFS - Changed branch name to lowercase but local path is not reflected

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control

I renamed a branch from "Main" to "main" and everything looks good in TFS. However, my Local Path still refers to the old name "Main". So for example:

Source location: $/MyTeamProject/main
Local Path: C:\MyTeamProject\Main

I have tried to clean my workspace and get specific version (latest), but it did not resolve the issue. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your local folder then get specific version (latest) again.

Comment: Just be careful if you have any local only code/branches!

Comment: I said in the question that I have already tried deleting local folder but that it didn't fix it...

Comment: My apologies, I tried to delete all the local folders and get specific version (latest) again and this time it works!

Comment: I need to make it clear the steps that I did to fix this issue in case it might help someone else. First, close down Visual Studio. I think this was the key. Delete all the local folders and then get specific version (latest).